# How does one add a new numeric surrogate key column to a table, with incremented numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So let's say you need to add an int column to a table and you want to add 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (etc.) to all of the rows for this new column.  What SQL would do this?  I'm guessing a for loop would be ideal (e.g. for each row in the table insert number + 1 and then increment the number)

What would you do?  If it matters I'm using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INT Identity

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD YOUR_COLUMN INT IDENTITY
```